# Data explorer is still showing incorrect data

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, data-explorer

I am trying to view the list of StackOverflow users based on their reputation. Following is the link

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/101107

However, the reputation of EVERYONE is still incorrect! Last Time I posted this question and I got an answer confirming it will be fixed by Sunday. But it seems like it is not!

What is happening? Or else did I do something wrong in query???

Please help!

Comment: Seems it hasn't updated in a while. See the front page http://data.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I didn't say it'd be fixed by Sunday. I said we usually refresh data on Sundays. We are currently rebuilding the machine that powers the Data Explorer, so it might be a bit longer before it's updated.

Comment: @AnnaLear: Thanks! I can see it is done!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The server that data.se runs on got a *lot* more usage from you guys once it was updated regularly, and we grew...grew too far for its hard disks to hold.

Tomorrow afternoon we'll be sticking in a new H710 RAID controller and additional SSDs to handle the growth of network data - **data.stackexchange.com will be unavailable during this time** as we *hopefully* just expand the secondary RAID array.  If the 1st RAID 1 array doesn't recover (the OS drives) then it'll be a full server rebuild and we'll be down a few hours longer.

Since this is really the only issue affecting our weekly refresh capacity, it'll return as soon as we're finished.

Comment: Thanks :). Can you please do me a favor? When it is done fixing, can you please drop a comment here? Hope to have a quick reply :)

Comment: Thanks! I can see it is done!